# Test integration between two rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, system-testing

I am developing a system composed of two different rails applications (server and client) which communicate via rest web services.

I have tests for each app individually, but I would like to add some test for the integration between the two platforms, to assert that one creates a request compatible with what the other is expecting.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you deploy your server (even locally) and write specs for client's integration module, letting it hit the real thing?

Comment: I can run them both locally, but I want to do it in an automated fashion, and don't know how to do the setup/start/stop of the server (if I run the test from the client app).

Comment: I do neither. But do you really need automatic startup/shutdown? You can easily launch it yourself and then treat just as an external dependency.

Comment: Maybe part of the client could ben written as a gem (e.g. the communication rest api). When the server app in testing mode can use the Client gem to run integration test. The client Rails app can also use the gem to make requests to the server.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar architecture and we are using VCR in order to record all server side responses and avoid make requests always. It could turn annoying and right now I'm looking for a way to clean data from server after every request

I think [VCR](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr/) could be a good start point in order to test integration between your apps.

You can find documentation here -> [Relish Docs](https://www.relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr/docs/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be several approaches here, depending what you have implemented..

1. If the client Rails app has user interface, try to write [Selenium tests](http://seleniumhq.org/) to perform the integration test in your local dev environment or a staging environment that has both deployed. (not ideal if the interface is still a prototype, changing frequently...)
2. Maybe part of the client can be written as a Ruby gem (e.g. the communication rest api is a ruby gem). When the server app in testing environment, the server Rails app can use the Client gem to run integration test, i.e. call the module function, the same function is used by client. The client Rails app can also use the gem to make requests to the server. [Here's a good guide](https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/gem-development.md) to start migrating some of your reusable code to rubygem.